# Failed to update security config. An error occurred during personalization

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-silicon

This Shows "csrutil failed to update security configuration for macintosh hd an error occurred during personalization". I have already tried csrutil clear and restart.

Comment: What are you trying to do when this happens?

Comment: Enable SIP.   This may have happened after turning SIP off/on many times.